# Is it possible to send a curly braced array of literals as a parameter in a Constructor?

Tags: c++

I don't understand why is it possible to do this:

```
int numbers[] = {-4,3,0,100,2000};
Set d(5,numbers);
```

but I get the following error when trying to do this:

```
Set d(5,{-4,3,0,100,2000});
```

```
Error:
warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x
         or -std=gnu++0x|
error: no matching function for call to
         'Set::Set(int, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
```

Constructor:

```
Set::Set(int size, const int constSet[])
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Whatever g++ flags you're passing don't allow that syntax.  The easiest solution is to just use -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x.

Comment: @Corbin are they allowed for arrays?

Comment: @SethCarnegie Am not actually sure, but the error/warning definitely seems to imply it.  I would imagine that the compiler just creates a temporary array on the stack and silently passes that.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Is this what you're talking about? http://ideone.com/NqUf4

Comment: @Pubby yes that's what I was talking about. Apparently it's not allowed then.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your constructor could take an `std::vector` and you can call it using `std::vector<int>{-4,3,0,100,2000}`. Also, if you take in the initializer list or anything, you won't need a size parameter.

Comment: @chris It did compile using std::vector, but now I get an error in execution, even if the constructor doesn't do anything.

Comment: @ednincer, how so? If you need to use the square bracket syntax, you could post that as a different problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not allowed in C++03, but the newest standard C++11 allows it.

See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Initializer_lists or this:  https://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#init-list

By the way, your constructor is actually taking a pointer, not an array.

Comment: I'd prefer this link. It's a bit more official: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#init-list

Comment: @chris Ok, I've added that to the post.

Comment: Thanks Pubby. But then the parameter won't be an array but a list, so I won't be able to use something like constSet[i] that I'm already using.  Is there another way to accept that kind of construction?

Comment: @ednincer You could try using variadic arguments where you would construct it like `Set d(-4,3,0,100,2000);`. Or you could do something like Boost.Assign with `d += -4, 3, 0, 100, 2000;`.

Comment: @Pubby, even better, C++-style variadic templates ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using newer version of C++, so When you compile this code make sure you do something like this:
    `g++ -std=c++0x sample.cpp -o sample`

`-std=c++0x` is important when you are using the newer version of c++

Comment: Compiling with -std=c++0x removes the warning but I have to change the second parameter to an initializer list<int> to remove the error, and well, change all the code inside...